# Showing all Assets in Azure portal, Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

Is there a commandlet in Azure Powershell for showing all current assets being used in Azure , including subscriptions,VM's,webapps, storage accounts...etc so we can generate an updated report at anytime  ?

Comment: are you using Resource Management or Service Management resources? - It will very likely require a small script of commands, but is certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Resource Manager (read New Portal), you can try the following to get a list of all the resources at the subscription level.

```
Get-AzureRmResource | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\all-resources.csv"
```

You will need to run this for all Subscriptions for which you want to fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks for your input , I'd like to get all subscriptions ,app services , vm's , actually everything in our Azure to have an updated list of what we have currently running , I'm not sure there is a commandlet out there yet for this .:(

Comment: You're correct. Resources are scoped to a subscription. What you would need to do is run the cmdlet for each and every subscription your account has access to. I'm not a PowerShell expert but I am sure you can loop through all subscription and run the above cmdlet.

Comment: I'm no expert in power shell either , I tried connecting these but failed , : Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Get-AzureStorageContainer | Get-AzureStorageBlob | Get-AzureRmSubscription | Get-AzureRmResource | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\all-resources.csv"